# MySQL search and replace some text in a field

Tags: mysql, sql, search, replace

What MySQL query will do a text search and replace in one particular field in a table?

I.e. search for `foo` and replace with `bar` so a record with a field with the value `hello foo` becomes `hello bar`.

Answer (score 553, accepted):

Change `table_name` and `field` to match your table name and field in question:

```
UPDATE table_name SET field = REPLACE(field, 'foo', 'bar') WHERE INSTR(field, 'foo') > 0;
```

- [REPLACE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) (string functions)
- [INSTR](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_instr) (string functions)

Comment: UPDATE [table_name] SET [field_name] = REPLACE(`[field_name]`, "foo", "bar");

Comment: I think it is faster not to use `WHERE instr(field, 'foo') > 0;` (so it would not perform 2 searches)... Am I wrong?

Comment: Can anyone comment on @inemanja's question? Would it be faster without the 'WHERE` clause?

Comment: Would this 'where' clause not mistakenly skip records with the string you're searching for occurring at position 0 in the field?

"INSTR(str,substr)
Returns the position of the first occurrence of substring substr in string str."
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_instr

Comment: @treddell, no positions start at 1 in SQL strings.

Comment: @inemanja, @Air without the `WHERE` clause  you do an `UPDATE` on all the rows...

Comment: Like Pring, if you're going to leave a comment like that, you might want to explain why.  Was it a mistake in the original advice, or a mistake on your part?  And you do know that before you make any sweeping changes to a database you are supposed to back it up first?

Comment: I can offer one more practical use for the full (plus `WHERE INSTR (...)`) version of this query: if you're simulating the query e.g. with a tool like PHPMyAdmin, the version that omits the `WHERE` clause returns every row in the database for the simulation. Not very useful for determining what's going to change.

Answer (score 101):

```
UPDATE table_name 
SET field = replace(field, 'string-to-find', 'string-that-will-replace-it');
```

Comment: Helped Me. For all the noobs, please remove the square brackets.

Comment: Note to the unwary: In this answer replace "field" with the **name** of the field that you want to modify. See answers below for clearer presentation of the syntax. In this answer, "field" is **not** an SQL keyword.

Answer (score 16):

In my experience, the fastest method is

```
UPDATE table_name SET field = REPLACE(field, 'foo', 'bar') WHERE field LIKE '%foo%';
```

The `INSTR()` way is the second-fastest and omitting the `WHERE` clause altogether is slowest, even if the column is not indexed.

Comment: Works for me because i need add another clause where.
UPDATE table_name SET field = REPLACE(field, 'foo', 'bar') WHERE field LIKE '%foo%' AND otherfield='foo22'

Comment: nice.  just replaced `http:` with `https:` on about 1000 rows.  super easy

Answer (score 11):

```
 UPDATE table SET field = replace(field, text_needs_to_be_replaced, text_required);
```

Like for example, if I want to replace all occurrences of John by Mark I will use below,

```
UPDATE student SET student_name = replace(student_name, 'John', 'Mark');
```

Answer (score 7):

And if you want to search and replace based on the value of another field you could do a CONCAT:

```
update table_name set `field_name` = replace(`field_name`,'YOUR_OLD_STRING',CONCAT('NEW_STRING',`OTHER_FIELD_VALUE`,'AFTER_IF_NEEDED'));
```

Just to have this one here so that others will find it at once.

Comment: If you quote the field name, [make sure you use the right kind of quotes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X6NJkWbM1xk)!

Answer (score 1):

The [Replace](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) string function will do that.

Comment: Works for me. It depends on how you interpret the question. If you need the database entries to change, then use `update`. Otherwise this solution is much better as it can be used without updating fields.

Answer (score 0):

I used the above command line as follow:
update TABLE-NAME set FIELD = replace(FIELD, 'And', 'and');
the purpose was to replace And with and ("A" should be lowercase). The problem is it cannot find the "And" in database, but if I use like "%And%" then it can find it along with many other ands that are part of a word or even the ones that are already lowercase.