# How can I use mySQL replace() to replace strings in multiple records?

Tags: mysql, replace

We have a database that has a bunch of records with some bad data in one column, in which an embedded editor escaped some stuff that shouldn't have been escaped and it's breaking generated links.

I want to run a query to replace the bad characters in all the records, but can't figure out how to do it. I found [the `replace()` function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) in MySQL, but how can I use it inside a query?

For example, what would be the correct syntax if I wanted to replace the string `&lt;` with an actual less-than angle bracket (`<`) in all records that have `&lt;` in the `articleItem` column? Can it be done in a single query (i.e. select and replace all in one swoop), or do I have to do multiple queries? Even if it's multiple queries, how do I use `replace()` to do the replace on the value of a field on more than one record?

Comment: before you do anything make sure you backup the database as well. You would also use update to update any field.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySql - Way to update portion of a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1876762/mysql-way-to-update-portion-of-a-string)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL search and replace some text in a field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/125230/mysql-search-and-replace-some-text-in-a-field)

Answer (score 446, accepted):

At a very generic level

```
UPDATE MyTable

SET StringColumn = REPLACE (StringColumn, 'SearchForThis', 'ReplaceWithThis')

WHERE SomeOtherColumn LIKE '%PATTERN%'
```

In your case you say these were escaped but since you don't specify how they were escaped, let's say they were escaped to `GREATERTHAN`

```
UPDATE MyTable

SET StringColumn = REPLACE (StringColumn, 'GREATERTHAN', '>')

WHERE articleItem LIKE '%GREATERTHAN%'
```

Since your query is actually going to be working inside the string, your `WHERE` clause doing its pattern matching is unlikely to improve any performance - it is actually going to generate more work for the server. Unless you have another WHERE clause member that is going to make this query perform better, you can simply do an update like this:

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET StringColumn = REPLACE (StringColumn, 'GREATERTHAN', '>')
```

You can also nest multiple `REPLACE` calls

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET StringColumn = REPLACE (REPLACE (StringColumn, 'GREATERTHAN', '>'), 'LESSTHAN', '<')
```

You can also do this when you select the data (as opposed to when you save it).

So instead of :

`SELECT MyURLString From MyTable`

You could do

`SELECT REPLACE (MyURLString, 'GREATERTHAN', '>') as MyURLString From MyTable`

Comment: minor quibble: GREATERTHAN is '>'

Answer (score 30):

```
UPDATE some_table SET some_field = REPLACE(some_field, '&lt;', '<')
```

Comment: Fixed the `&lt;` s. You need to use the encoding of &, like so: `&amp;` :)

Comment: I re-edited it. Thanks for letting me know. It dawned on me moments after I said I didn't know how.  Thats the way my world works. :)

Comment: thank you! this worked perfectly update a domain url as a substring replacement in a huge blog database!

Answer (score 7):

Check this

```
UPDATE some_table SET some_field = REPLACE("Column Name/String", 'Search String', 'Replace String')
```

Eg with sample string:

```
UPDATE some_table SET some_field = REPLACE("this is test string", 'test', 'sample')
```

EG with Column/Field Name:

```
UPDATE some_table SET some_field = REPLACE(columnName, 'test', 'sample')
```

Answer (score 4):

you can write a stored procedure like this:

> CREATE PROCEDURE sanitize_***TABLE***()
>
> BEGIN
>
> *#replace space with underscore*
>
> UPDATE ***Table*** SET ***FieldName*** = REPLACE(***FieldName***," ","_") WHERE ***FieldName*** is not NULL;
>
> *#delete dot*
>
> UPDATE ***Table*** SET ***FieldName*** = REPLACE(***FieldName***,".","") WHERE ***FieldName*** is not NULL;
>
> *#delete (*
>
> UPDATE ***Table*** SET ***FieldName*** = REPLACE(***FieldName***,"(","") WHERE ***FieldName*** is not NULL;
>
> *#delete )*
>
> UPDATE ***Table*** SET ***FieldName*** = REPLACE(***FieldName***,")","") WHERE ***FieldName*** is not NULL;
>
> *#raplace or delete any char you want*
>
> *#..........................*
>
> END

In this way you have modularized control over table.

You can also generalize stored procedure making it, parametric with table to sanitoze input parameter

Comment: those null checks are redundant

Comment: Are there any easy and safe tools to create mysql stored procedure?

Answer (score 1):

This will help you.

```
UPDATE play_school_data SET title= REPLACE(title, "&#39;", "'") WHERE title = "Elmer&#39;s Parade";
```

Result:

```
title = Elmer's Parade
```