# Possible with MYSQL replace()?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Is the following possible with just a sql query or do I need to create a php routine?

I have a database of members with gmail addresses, most of which contain 1 or more '.' (dots) in the address before the '@'

For the purposes of thwarting duplicate/multiple signups I am creating a new column that will contain the 'clean' gmail address so I can make comparisons going forward on new registrations.

Example... I have rows which the following gmail addresses are actually all the same in the eyes of gmail.

```
myname@gmail.com
m.yname@gmail.com
my.name@gmail.com
m.y.n.a.m.e@gmail.com
```

I know replace() can simply replace something with something, but I want to replace all dots before the @

Is there a sql function/statement I can use to clean up *all* the dots *before* the '@' or do I have to create a php routine to achieve this?

Comment: So what did you try already?

Comment: Just out of curiosity.. but my.name@gmail.com is definatly another email address then myname@gmail.com. Wouldn't "fixing" these email adresses actually break the data in your database?

Comment: Maybe this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986826/how-to-do-a-regular-expression-replace-in-mysql

Comment: @DamienOvereem. For gmail, those are the same. that's what he is trying to say. sending one email to those 4 mails will always send it to the same unique email address of myname@gmail.com

Comment: @FilipeSilva are you sure , all are same for gmail...

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/25512

Comment: @KuldeepChoudhary. yep. :) see [here](http://gmailblog.blogspot.pt/2008/03/2-hidden-ways-to-get-more-from-your.html)

Comment: @DamienOvereem No they are the same. Google created this for filtering options. Dots before the @ are irrelevant. All the emails I show above will all go to myname@gmail.com. Very similar a gmail usr can also add keywords with a '+'. Example, myname+list1@gmail.com will go to myname@gmail.com.

Comment: Interesting, didn't know google handled email adresses that way.

Comment: Presumably, you'll want to ignore any portions after any + as well?

Comment: @RowlandShaw That is already taken care of at registration by not allowing '+' in an email address.

Comment: @user1687533 In that case, I can't ever be your customer, as I have a `+` in my real email address...

Comment: @RowlandShaw It is only the case of gmail, googlemail, and hotmail/live domains. MS added the use of keywords with plus sign as well. Real addresses where the plus sign is actually part of the real address are not affected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select concat(replace(substring(email, 1, locate('@', email)-1), '.', '') , substring(email, locate('@', email), length(email)))
```

Comment: This was the first one I tried and it did indeed give me the results I wanted. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT CONCAT(REPLACE(LEFT(email,LOCATE('@',email)-1), '.', ''),RIGHT(email, LOCATE('@',email))) FROM your_table.
```

Comment: The basic algorithm here is as follows: split the address on the '@' sign, replace all dots in the left part, and concat the parts back together.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a mix of [`CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat), [`REPLACE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace), [`SUBSTRING`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring) and [`LOCATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_locate):

```
SELECT
    `email`,
    CONCAT(
        REPLACE(
            SUBSTRING(
                `email`,
                1, 
                LOCATE(
                    '@', 
                    `email`
                ) - 1
            ),
            '.', 
            ''
        ),
        '@',
        SUBSTRING(
            `email`,
            LOCATE(
                '@', 
                `email`
            ) + 1
        )
    ) as `email_clean`
FROM
    `emails`
```

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e92a2/1)

```
┌──────────────────────┬─────────────────────┐
│        EMAIL         │     EMAIL_CLEAN     │
├──────────────────────┼─────────────────────┤
│ bar@foo.bar.com      │ bar@foo.bar.com     │
│ foo-bar@bar-foo.com  │ foo-bar@bar-foo.com │
│ foo.b.ar@bar.foo.com │ foobar@bar.foo.com  │
│ foo.bar@bar.foo.com  │ foobar@bar.foo.com  │
│ foo@bar.com          │ foo@bar.com         │
└──────────────────────┴─────────────────────┘
```

Comment: It gives wrong output. I inserted record foo.b.ar@bar.foo.com and it returns foo@bar.com. Check this fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e92a2/1

Comment: @AshReva Cannot confirm? Did you check your link?

Answer (score 0):

You can identify the section before the @, replace the dots, and then combine it with everything after the @:

```
SET @EMAIL='my.name@gmail.com';
SELECT CONCAT(REPLACE(LEFT(@EMAIL,INSTR(@EMAIL,'@')),'.',''),RIGHT(@EMAIL,CHAR_LENGTH(@EMAIL)-INSTR(@EMAIL,'@')))
```

The LEFT and RIGHT are used to split the string, the INSTR used to determine where to split the string, and the CONCAT chucks it all back together again.  These sorts of things can be built up a step at a time - I started with finding my @, then getting the stuff to the LHS and so on...

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE some_table SET some_field = REPLACE(some_field, '&lt;', '<')
```

Please see the Ref URL : [How can I use mySQL replace() to replace strings in multiple records?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271186/how-can-i-use-mysql-replace-to-replace-strings-in-multiple-records)

hope this is useful for all of us.

At a very generic level

```
UPDATE MyTable

SET StringColumn = REPLACE (StringColumn, 'SearchForThis', 'ReplaceWithThis')

WHERE SomeOtherColumn LIKE '%PATTERN%'
```

In your case you say these were escaped but since you don't specify how they were escaped, let's say they were escaped to GREATERTHAN

```
UPDATE MyTable

SET StringColumn = REPLACE (StringColumn, 'GREATERTHAN', '<')

WHERE articleItemLIKE '%GREATERTHAN%'
```

Since your query is actually going to be working inside the string, your WHERE clause doing its pattern matching is unlikely to improve any performance - it is actually going to generate more work for the server. Unless you have another WHERE clause member that is going to make this query perform better, you can simply do an update like this:

```
UPDATE MyTable

SET StringColumn = REPLACE (StringColumn, 'GREATERTHAN', '<')
```

Coming in from a completely different angle:

You can do this when you select the data (not when you do save it)

So instead of :

```
SELECT MyURLString From MyTable
```

You can do

```
SELECT REPLACE (MyURLString, 'GREATERTHAN', '<') as MyURLString From MyTable
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a query which strips the first dots from the "name"-part in the mail adress

```
SET @mailAddress := 'm.y.n.a.m.e@gmail.com';
SELECT @mailAddress, 
    REPLACE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@mailAddress, '@', 1), '.', '') namePart,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(@mailAddress, '@', -1) domainPart,
    CONCAT(REPLACE(
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(@mailAddress, '@', 1)
    , '.', ''),
    '@',
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(@mailAddress, '@', -1)
) email;
```

Result:

```
@mailAddress            namePart  domainPart  email
--------------------------------------------------------------
m.y.n.a.m.e@gmail.com   myname    gmail.com   myname@gmail.com
```

SQLFiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/25514