# Mysql update query to remove the single quotes from name field

Tags: mysql

I have set of results in my table which contain the character `'`. These characters are contained in a person's name. For example, in my **Persons** table some names are stored as,

```
Bill' Murray
Andy' Griffin
```

I can find such names from my table using the query,

```
SELECT * FROM Persons WHERE first_name LIKE '%\''
```

I need to update the information of these people by removing the `'`. So after updating, I need the values as,

```
Bill Murray
Andy Griffin
```

Comment: i think this is what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271186/how-can-i-use-mysql-replace-to-replace-strings-in-multiple-records

Answer (score 6):

Check Below query

```
Update TableName set FieldName=replace(FieldName,'''','')
```