# Trouble with this "Update" command

Tags: php, sql

I was given an sql database that I was supposed to do some stuff on, and I want to clean it up, given that they have stuff with "special characters" as values, such as `carcaças`. Notice the `ç.

My Update command just simply doesn't want to work. I've checked in a million times and the weird part is on the webservice that I'm creating using that database the line seems to do nothing, but when I go on phpmyadmin it works perfectly. It has nothing to do with permissions given that its all being hosted on my computer.

So here you go the code:

```
function filter($stockconn){
    mysqli_query($stockconn,"UPDATE produtos SET familiaprod='Carcacas' WHERE familiaprod='Carcaças'") or die(mysql_error());
    mysqli_close($stockconn);
}
```

So far its all very simple, simple connection file (which is working correctly 100%) being pulled towards that function.

Comment: For one thing, change `die(mysql_error()` to `die(mysqli_error($stockconn)`

Comment: Plus, `carcaças` may not be the same as `Carcaças` with the uppercase `C` should that be the case.

Comment: Oh ye i forgot i was using mysqli, yep changed and still no outputed error message.

Comment: What matters here is your table or column's [collation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-charsets.html), which will determine whether `Carcacas` is treated the same or differently from `Carcaças`

Comment: Do you have multiple records containing that string, or just one row?

Comment: Ye fred but the thing is, if that was the case when i tried it on phpmyadmin it wouldn't have worked but it did, which shows the problem is with this outter syntax or something :S

Comment: carcaça is a product "category" so i have multiple rows with that string.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything. As for multiple rows, that one I don't know how to update "all" rows containing a particular string, but am sure I'd find a way to do it.

Comment: This will probably help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

Comment: Tried adding that to no result, the thing is, when i run that command on phpmyadmin it works fine, updates all the rows etc etc, what is really weird is that when i run it on the webservice/website it does nothing, even tried isolating the code, to no result.

Comment: See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/4271225/ I think you need `REPLACE`

Comment: @davidsbro, I think you should have rejected that edit. There was much more the editor could have done.

Comment: Alright guys i have the solution, i was a bit suspicious it had something to do with the charset, and indeed it had, i had tried giving the document diferent charsets but it didnt work, altho with the link provided by @Mihai i ended up setting the database's charset to utf8mb4 and it changed rows sucessfully, tyvm for all the help.

     function filter($stockconn, $opencartconn){
   mysqli_set_charset($stockconn, 'utf8mb4');
   mysqli_query($stockconn,"UPDATE produtos SET familiaprod='Carcacas' WHERE familiaprod='Carcaças'") or die(mysqli_error());
   mysqli_close($stockconn);
  }

Comment: Post it as an answer and accept it.

Comment: Great, glad to hear it. `Another happy ending` ;-)

Comment: @gunr2171, I agree completely; however, it was already approved by three other editors, so I just decided to fix a couple obvious things. But I completely agree; some reviewers seem to approve everything (like a 20 to 1 approve/reject ratio). I normally would reject an edit like that. I think there are too many robo-reviewers...http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5213908