# How to replace words in a sql database

Tags: mysql, replace

i need to replace only the domain of an URL present in many rows of a database with a different one. For example, the current URLs are something like www.myoldsite.com/index?s=something and i need to replace only the domain so they will look like www.mynewsite.com/index?s=something and so on. Is it even possible to do that in mysql?

I know how to update and set full values for all rows in a table having certain value but not only part of them with this:

```
UPDATE `mydatabase`.`mytable` SET `mycolumn` = 'http://mynewsite.com/' WHERE `mycolumn` = 'http://myoldsite.com/';
```

What can i do in this case?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  Use the function `replace()`:

```
UPDATE mydatabase.mytable
    SET mycolumn = replace(mycolumn, 'http://myoldsite.com', 'http://mynewsite.com/')
    WHERE `mycolumn` like 'http://myoldsite.com/%';
```

This isn't perfect, if the old site appears more than once in the URL.

Perhaps a better way is:

```
UPDATE mydatabase.mytable
    SET mycolumn = concat('http://mynewsite.com/',
                          substr(mycolumn, length('http://myoldsite.com/')
                         )
    WHERE `mycolumn` like 'http://myoldsite.com/%';
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for something like

```
UPDATE MyTable

SET StringColumn = REPLACE (StringColumn, 'SearchForThis', 'ReplaceWithThis')

WHERE SomeOtherColumn LIKE '%PATTERN%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`REPLACE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) to replace the domain when you've found matches:

```
UPDATE mydatabase.mytable 
SET `mycolumn` = REPLACE(mycolumn, 'http://myoldsite.com', 'http://mynewsite.com/') 
WHERE `mycolumn` LIKE 'http://myoldsite.com/%'; -- wildcard on the end
```

The WHERE clause may be unnecessary here, but might be good for reference

Answer (score 0):

you need to see -->
[How can I use mySQL replace() to replace strings in multiple records?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271186/how-can-i-use-mysql-replace-to-replace-strings-in-multiple-records)
so, you can update strings ...

> UPDATE `mydatabase`.`mytable` SET `mycolumn`=REPLACE(`mycolumn`, 'old url', 'new url') where `mycolumn`='%old_url%'

you must be modified to fit the purpose.