# How to replace a string in mySQL row that has many strings separated by commas?

Tags: php, mysql

In mySQL under the column `extra` I have fields like the following (in one field per row)

```
Radio CD,Immobilizer,Multitronic Cr,Air Condition
```

The problem is that instead of `Multitronic Car` I wrote `Multitronic Cr` without `a` in about 300 rows.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the [similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271186/how-can-i-use-mysql-replace-to-replace-strings-in-multiple-records) but in your case it should be similar to:

```
UPDATE table_name

SET `extra` = REPLACE (`extra`, 'Multitronic Cr', 'Multitronic Car')

WHERE `extra` LIKE '%Multitronic Cr%'
```

Comment: efxaristo file alla den katalavo to articleItem

Comment: copy/paste error, should be your column name. fixed now. Also put your correct `table_name` in there.

Comment: thank you. douleveis kapou i ise monos sou ?

Comment: Kai se eteria kai monos mou file giati?

Comment: logika tha me endiaferei sinergasia per projects ke exo ellipsi prosopikou. en exeis kapoio link sto profile sou i kati

Comment: chat here: http://www.chatzy.com/25282097780494 me password arithmous 654321

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63631/discussion-between-kypros-and-xalloumokkelos).

Comment: tora to eida to minima