# MySQL SQL Query to Delete a String From Records

Tags: mysql, sql

I need a MySQL Statement to delete the following string from the text in the field called `post_content`

E.g. String: `[css3_grid id='gcse']`, How can I do it?

Comment: Please look here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271186/how-can-i-use-mysql-replace-to-replace-strings-in-multiple-records

Comment: It's columns, not fields...

Comment: You should remove the PHP tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [REPLACE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) function.

```
UPDATE table SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, 'String: [css3_grid id=''gcse'']', '');
```

Comment: If it's a huge table it can be nice to also have WHERE post_content like '%String: [css3_grid id=''gcse'']%', to make transaction smother.

Answer (score -1):

You're going to want to do something like this:

```
UPDATE table SET post_content = REPLACE( '[css3_grid id=\'gcse\']' , '' , post_content )
```

Comment: I think you have the orders of the parameters wrong.

Comment: it is highly likely that I do. that's why I would use the google first before actually doing it. ;)