# Remove all characters between 2 characters in a String

Tags: java, string, char, between, removeall

I have a database with 50000 rows. I want to get all rows one by one, put them into a String variable and delete all characters between "(" and ")", then update the row. I just don't know how to delete all characters between "(" and ")". I want to do this with java.

Comment: FYI: Doing this in Java is likely to be MUCH slower than handling this with pure SQL.

Comment: When you see the light(TM), see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271186/how-can-i-use-mysql-replace-to-replace-strings-in-multiple-records

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your regular expression would be something like:

```
data.replaceAll("\\(.*?\\)", "()"); //if you want to keep the brackets
```

OR

```
data.replaceAll("\\(.*?\\)", ""); //if you don't want to keep the brackets
```

The string consists of 3 parts:

```
\\(  //This part matches the opening bracket
.*?  //This part matches anything in between
\\)  //This part matches the closing bracket
```

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Use the `replaceall(string regex, string replacement)` statement, like this:

```
data.replaceall(" and ", "");
```

Comment: can you copy the content of the string here?

Comment: String temp = "Bold (medium) ...";
I need to Remove (medium) and make my string like this "Bold  ..."

Comment: try with temp.replace("(medium)","");

Comment: I told i have 50000 string which are diffrent and i need to delete every character in this strings between "(" and ")". All i need is a code that remove all characters between 2 special character.

Comment: String s = "ab(cd)e";
s = s.replaceAll("\\(.*?\\)", "()"); // ab()e

Comment: Sorry, i haven´t seen that it's says BETWEEN with that regular expression (regx) should work!

Comment: it didn't work again. I use your regx but gave me an error: 
Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ )
I really need this :(

Comment: @Matarata You need to escape the backslashes in java code before regex evaluation: s.replaceAll("\\\(.*?\\\)", "()");