# How to replace apostrophe in database via sql

Tags: mysql

I am trying to replace `"?t"` string to `"'t"` (apostrophe t)

I enter this command in phpMyAdmin

```
UPDATE "myTable"
SET "myColumn" = REPLACE ("myColumn", "\?t", "\'t")
```

as suggested in [How can I use mySQL replace() to replace strings in multiple records?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271186/how-can-i-use-mysql-replace-to-replace-strings-in-multiple-records))

I get this error

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near UPDATE "myTable"
SET "myColumn" = REPLACE ("myColumn", "\?t", "\'t") at line 1
```

What is wrong with my command?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't quote table or column names. If you need to escape them use backticks

```
UPDATE `myTable`
SET `myColumn` = REPLACE (`myColumn`, '?t', '\'t')
```