# php remove special characters

Tags: php, arrays

I have a string like this in the database

```
!80!n!98!n!22!n!6!n!76!n!1!n!24!n!129!n!59!n!73!n!7!n!40!n!85!n!35!n!42!n!126!n!81!n!37!n!128!n!147!n!106!n
```

I want to remove those ! and n symbols and want to add a pipe in between characters

```
80|98|22|6|76|1|24|129|59|73|7|40|85|35|42|126|81|37|128|147|106
```

Answer (score 1):

you could update the column first:

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET StringColumn = REPLACE (StringColumn, '!n!', '|')
WHERE SomeOtherColumn LIKE '%PATTERN%'
```

More information on replace here:
[How can I use mySQL replace() to replace strings in multiple records?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271186/how-can-i-use-mysql-replace-to-replace-strings-in-multiple-records)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$str="!80!n!98!n!22!n!6!n!76!n!1!n!24!n!129!n!59!n!73!n!7!n!40!n!85!n!35!n!42!n!126!n!81!n!37!n!128!n!147!n!106!n
";
 $str1 = preg_replace('/\s+/','|',str_replace(array("!n","!","!n!"),' ',trim($str)));
 echo $output = substr($str1, 1, -1);
```

OUTPUT

> 80|98|22|6|76|1|24|129|59|73|7|40|85|35|42|126|81|37|128|147|106