# Remove all characters from the string

Tags: mysql, sql, replace

I have a MySQL database with about 20.000 entries where files are named `Name_Subname_XXXXX`. Because the files are named that way, the name that shows to the internet itself also get's that name when entered into the database.

I wonder how can I in an easy way remove the `_` from the name and just keep `Name Subname XXXXX`?

Comment: $newfilename = str_replace('_',' ',$filename);

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I use mySQL replace() to replace strings in multiple records?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271186/how-can-i-use-mysql-replace-to-replace-strings-in-multiple-records)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use MySQL's [REPLACE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) method for strings:

```
UPDATE tbl SET filename = REPLACE(filename, '_', ' ');
```

Comment: Will that work for all _ ? it varies from X_X_X_X_ to X_X.

Comment: @Rizzler Yes, it will.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`replace`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_replace):

```
select replace(col, '_', ' ') from tbl
```

Comment: Will that work for all _ ? it varies from X_X_X_X_ to X_X.

Comment: @Rizzzler: yes, it will.

Answer (score 0):

use `replace()`

```
SELECT REPLACE(col, '_', ' ') from table;
```

Ref https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you probably want to split the name into three columns (as opposed to just removing an underscore in a name).  If so, use `substring_index()`:

```
select substring_index(filename, '_', 1) as name,
       substring_index(substring_index(filename, '_', 2), '_', -1) as subname,
       substring_index(filename, '_', -1) as xxxxx
```