# How to update multiple row data in a single query?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have multiple rows in database.

I need to collect all the rows based on certain condition and change the value of particular column by removing a word from the column's value.

How it could be done with with CakePHP 3?

Comment: Do you want to fetch or update the record

Comment: UPDATE website_content_pages SET content = REPLACE(content, 'b>', 'strong>'); try this query in sql it's do both  work it not work in cakephp 3.x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this on top of the controller "use Cake\Datasource\ConnectionManager;"

```
$this->loadModel('Rewards');
$connection = ConnectionManager::get('default');
$results = $connection->execute("UPDATE rewards SET description =  REPLACE (description, 's', 'a') where is_disabled=1");
```

I have values in description fields 'wwss' now that fields word replace into 'wwaa' like that.

For more explanation refer this link

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/database-basics.html

[How can I use mySQL replace() to replace strings in multiple records?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271186/how-can-i-use-mysql-replace-to-replace-strings-in-multiple-records)

Please review,Thanks!

Comment: Why are you answering your own question as if you don't know the person who asked the question?

Comment: @AD7six Hi 1st searched the answer for this question and got the answer from the document it works perfect to me.so i post the answer for my question

Comment: Answering your own question is great (and encouraged) adding this when self answering is quite bizarre `I hope this is usefull for your question.Please review,Thanks!`

Comment: @AD7six i am sry. it's my careless :) Now i edit and updated my question

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
$model->updateAll(
        ['description' => "REPLACE (description, 's', 'a')"], // fields
        ['is_disabled' => 1] //condition
);
```

This will generate the following sql:

```
UPDATE 
    mytable
SET 
    description =  REPLACE (description, 's', 'a') 
WHERE
     is_disabled = 1
```

Note that this is replacing the matching string ('s') everywhere where it appears in the description field - even in the middle of a word. This often leads to wellknown [clbuttic mistakes](http://thedailywtf.com/articles/The-Clbuttic-Mistake-).

Comment: `change the value of particular column by removing a word from the column's value.` The updateAll call in this answer doesn't do that, or make it apparent how it could be changed to do that.

Comment: I've amended the answer so that it answers the question - in future it is a better idea to only write an answer, if it does actually answer the question. Thanks for using whitespace in your code examples - please do keep up that habit (and fix your existing questions/answers which don't do this).

Comment: "REPLACE (description, 's', 'a')" totally this values are updated into my columns