# MySql Replace part of a string with escape characters

Tags: mysql, string, url, replace

I'm trying to do a simple update the old url in a database table with a new relative url, but I keep getting "0 rows affected". I think it might have to do with the escape characters in the string?

The URLs in the column 'data' now are structured with the backslash.
Here's my SQL:

```
 UPDATE vjfl_sliderimages
 SET data = REPLACE(data, '\/myolddomain.com\/images\/', '\/images\/')
```

This should work to change the URL of every image from myolddomain.com/images/ to /images/ but for some reason it just doesn't have any affect.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who has this issue, use CONCAT SQL function with CHAR(92) which correspond to '\' ASCII char.

Example:

```
UPDATE vjfl_sliderimages SET data = REPLACE(data, CONCAT(CHAR(92), '/myolddomain.com', CHAR(92), '/images', CHAR(92), '/'), CONCAT(CHAR(92), '/images', CHAR(92), '/'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Escape characters(/) are treated differently in MySQL or SQL VARCHAR fields.
Try

```
 UPDATE vjfl_sliderimages
 SET data = REPLACE(date, '////myolddomain.com////images////', '////images////');
```

If 4 splashes doesn't work then try for 3.

Comment: Thanks Gaurav Lad. I tried with 4, 3 and 2 slashes and it has no effect. The message says "Your SQL query has been executed successfully", but nothing changes.

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271186/how-can-i-use-mysql-replace-to-replace-strings-in-multiple-records
And integrate my above answer with it.

Comment: UPDATE vjfl_sliderimages
 SET data = REPLACE(data, '////myolddomain.com////images////', '////images////') WHERE data like '%////myolddomain.com////images////%';
Try this, let me know if it works.

Comment: Nope. "0 rows affected". Tried with 3 and 4 slashes.

Comment: How much records does `SELECT` query returning your.
Try running `SELECT * FROM Table_name where FieldName like '////myolddomain.com////images////';`

Answer (score 0):

As it is forward slash so no need of escape symbol.

```
UPDATE vjfl_sliderimages SET data = REPLACE(data,'/myolddomain.com/images/', '/images/');
```

Edit:-
if the previous url was myolddomain.com/images/

then query must be

```
UPDATE vjfl_sliderimages SET data = REPLACE(data,'myolddomain.com/images/', '/images/');
```

Comment: Thanks Naruto. I tried that initially, but it returns "0 rows affected".

Comment: can you place exact url....As i have checked in my local database and it is running perfectly...I have edited answer if your domain name was myolddomain.com/images/

Comment: This database was migrated from my local server to a live server. The URL on my local server was http://192.168.10.15/myolddomain.com/images/. The  slider component used what it considered to be a relative URL of /myolddomain.com/images, which no longer works on the live server for obvious reasons. That's why there is a leading slash. Now that it's on the live server, the URL to the images are all wrong. I could manually edit them, but there are many and it would take hours.