# MYSql change only year from timestamp

Tags: mysql

Accidentally, my host had set the time for 2012 and in my database, there are more than 4000 records updated timestamp column as `2012-11-21 11:24:40`.

I cant change time on all columns while updating, I need to keep the same time as per the table column, I just need to change only year `2012` to `2016` in that table.

I listed all columns using this query,

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `del_date` LIKE '%2012-11-21%';
```

but do not know to change the year only in that column.

Please help how can I change the same.

Comment: Is it text or actual timestamp datatype? If latter, add four years to it

Comment: it is actual timestamp, but I resolved with the help of this thread, http://stackoverflow.com/a/4271225/4306705. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can use [ADDDATE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_adddate), like

```
UPDATE yourTableName SET del_date = ADDDATE(del_date, INTERVAL 4 YEAR);
```

Comment: I used like this, `UPDATE `table` SET `del_date` = REPLACE( `del_date` , '2012', '2016' )` . Is that correct?

Comment: @yuri1000 yes that can also be the solution