# Mysql Update Query , update column values in one query

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I want to update a column values in a single query.

[image]

Want to update column values in a single query as shown on above image like 
POS-01 -> PL-01 
POS-02 -> PL-02 
POS-03 -> PL-03 
POS-04 -> PL-04 
POS-05 -> PL-05 
POS-06 -> PL-06 
And so on......upto end of table records.
How to do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use mySQL replace() to replace strings in multiple records?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271186/how-can-i-use-mysql-replace-to-replace-strings-in-multiple-records)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this Scenario this query will help.

```
update tbl_possession_letter set pos_letter_no=replace(pos_letter_no, 'POS-','PL-');
```