# MySQL RegExp Replace

Tags: php, mysql, regex

Here is my situation:

My company hosts multiple sites for clients, and the content of the sites are stored in a MySQL database.

I have an issue where I need to go through the whole database and replace pieces of the content.  For example:

I need to replace **http://downloads.mysever.com/siteID/someImage.jpg** with **//downloads.mysever.com/siteID/someImage.jpg**

So I just need to remove the **http:** from all links that are going to our downloads server.

My question is what would be the best way to go about this?  Will I need to write a php script to handle this, or am I able to use just MySQL to accomplish this.

Thanks

Comment: There is no "best way" to do something so trivial. Use whatever tools you are most comfortable with.

Comment: `UPDATE table SET col = SUBSTR(col, 6)`

Comment: So is this possible just using MySQL?  I wasn't sure if regular expressions were possible in MySQL.  I would prefer to write a query that would be able to handle it, but if needed I can write a PHP script.

Comment: @noub Why would you need a regex? You're just stripping the first 5 chars. At worst just find/replace `http:` with an empty string, still doesn't require a regex

Comment: The location of the links that need to be modified are not static, so I cannot use SUBSTR like that.  I have columns in tables that hold the header code, body code, and content for each individual page.  There is no way of knowing exactly where the links are.

Comment: So just `UPDATE table SET col = REPLACE(col, 'http:', '')` then

Comment: Regular expressions are not a magic wand that is the best solution to every problem that relates to strings.

Answer (score 2):

you can use the sql statement

```
 UPDATE tablename SET url = REPLACE(url, 'http:', '');
```

Read [this](http://davidwalsh.name/mysql-replace) blog post

You can execute this command using the command line

```
mysql -uUSERNAME -p DATABASE_NAME -e "UPDATE tablename SET url = REPLACE(url, 'http:', '')";
```

Answer (score 2):

you could do this with pure mysql:

```
update table set field = REPLACE(field, 'http:', '') where INSTR(field, 'http:') > 0;
```

see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125230/mysql-search-and-replace-some-text-in-a-field)

Comment: Note that the WHERE condition is not required

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to take the database offline briefly, I've found the easiest way is to:

1. use mysqldump to export the entire database
2. run a find-and-replace in whichever editor you prefer to update the database dump
3. recreate the database from the dump file - make sure it all went correctly, then replace the original database with the new version.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL does offer regular expression functionality.  The functionality is probably too detailed to go into here so here is the link:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/regexp.html

A basic usage example for you sample case would be:

```
UPDATE table SET field = REPLACE(field, 'http:', '') WHERE field REGEXP '^http:'
```

Note however that this case could be done without regular expression by simply doing this:

```
UPDATE table SET field = REPLACE(field, 'http:', '') WHERE field LIKE 'http:%'
```

So you might not need to use regular expressions for each type of replacement you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

To remove the leading `'http:'` string (from a character type column) of all rows in a table, then something as simple as this will work:

```
UPDATE mytable
   SET mycol = SUBSTRING(mycol,6)
 WHERE mycol LIKE 'http:%'
```

---

**UPDATE:**

Note that using the `REPLACE` function will replace ALL occurrences of the specified string from a string; it may not be appropriate for removing just the leading occurrence of a specified string.

If you want to remove ALL occurrences of 'http:' found within column values, then:

```
UPDATE mytable
   SET mycol = REPLACE( mycol , 'http:, '')
 WHERE mycol LIKE '%http:%'
```

---

MySQL does provide support for regular expressions, specifically, for finding values that match a given regular expression; but MySQL does not provides support for "replacement" using a regular expression.

So you could use this in a query:

```
 WHERE mycol REGEXP 'http:'
```

in place of (equivalent to):

```
 WHERE mycol LIKE '%http:%'
```