# Double Quotes in MySQL UPDATE Query

Tags: mysql

I'm using the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125230/mysql-search-and-replace-some-text-in-a-field) to make changes to a text field in multiple records in a MySQL table.

I need to change a small portion of each record where a URL occurs with double quotes.

Example record:

```
a:32:{s:5:"title";s:23:"Texas"footertext";s:220:"<a class=\"footerlink\" href=\"%ORIGINALPOSTURL%\" target=\"_blank\" rel=\"nofollow\">CLICK HERE FOR MORE INFO &amp; PHOTOS</a>}
```

I want to remove the `target=\"_blank\"`

I'm not updating any records I suspect due to the use of double quotes in the target value I'm trying to replace.  I've tried with and without backslashes.  These 4 backslashes on each side of the double quotes you see here worked when performing a SELECT in phpMyAdmin.  I've tried a single backslash with zero records updated too.

Neither of these worked

```
UPDATE wp_autoblog SET feed_meta = replace(feed_meta,'target=\\\\"_blank\\\\"','');

UPDATE wp_autoblog SET feed_meta = replace(feed_meta,'target=\"_blank\"','');
```

Comment: Can you show a sample string of what you are trying to replace?

Comment: This is a sample of what is in the database field exactly: <a class=\"footerlink\" href=\"%ORIGINALPOSTURL%\" target=\"_blank\" rel=\"nofollow\">CLICK HERE FOR MORE INFO &amp; PHOTOS</a>

Comment: Single backslash should be working.  Is this a raw query or what is being fed into your PHP code?

Comment: I'm pasting that directly into myPHPAdmin...also tried this with no luck

Comment: I only want to remove the target portion of this link...is that the problem?

Comment: Update your question showing everything you have tried.

Comment: I've updated the question with all the information I've tried and a full record.

Comment: Can you try this query and let us know what output you get: `SELECT 'target=\"_blank\"' FROM wp_autoblog` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102568/discussion-between-rocco-the-taco-and-tim-biegeleisen).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen is 100% is should have worked fine.  It was how myPHPadmin was displaying the backslashed versus what was really in the DB.  I assume due to how myPHPadmin handles inserts in its own interface?  Either way, its working, thanks Tim.

Comment: That looks like data treated with PHP’s `serialize` function¹. Which means you can not just randomly replace single parts of it; you would need to modify the `s:220` part, too – otherwise it won’t de-serialize properly any more. (¹ Well, apart from stuff like this `s:23:"Texas"footertext"` it does – that would be invalid already.)

Comment: @CBroe Yes, I realized that later...I successfully updated the data only to have it break the overall outcome.  What is the saying?  Be careful what you ask for, you just might get it and not like the results.  LOL.

Comment: The proper way to do this would be to load the record(s) into a PHP script, unserialize the data, modify it, serialize it again, and then store it back … (of course, depending on the number of records to work on, that can perform anywhere from fine, to terrible, to the script getting killed off by the defined max runtime setting …)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out phpMyAdmin inserts an extra backslash when displaying the data in a web browser.

I ended up doing a .sql dump of the table and the data I'm trying to replace is wrapped like this: `target=\\\"_blank\\\"`

I issued the followed command and it worked great.

```
UPDATE wp_autoblog SET feed_meta = REPLACE( feed_meta,  'target=\\\"_blank\\\"',  '' )
```