# I can't access my WordPress dashboard after logging into Wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, ftp

After I log into Wordpress, I am taken straight to the homepage instead of the dashboard. I see the thin gray bar at the top that shows that I'm logged in, but there are no links to the dashboard there either.

When I access the site while not logged in, I get this error message:

> Warning: require(/home/content/p3pnexwpnas12_data03/22/3844422/html/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/content/p3pnexwpnas12_data03/22/3844422/html/wp-settings.php on line 151
>
>     Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/home/content/p3pnexwpnas12_data03/22/3844422/html/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/php5_6/lib/php') in /home/content/p3pnexwpnas12_data03/22/3844422/html/wp-settings.php on line 151

This was a manual migration from a subdomain of another domain to this one. I'm assuming the fix is in phpMyAdmin, but I'm out of ideas for where to look. Or should I look in another file in the FTP for possible problems.

This is on a GoDaddy Managed Wordpress hosting plan, so I have pretty limited access to things. For example, I can't just delete all of the files and folders in the FTP and use BackupBuddy to migrate the site like I'm used to.

Any ideas of where to look or articles to read would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

The domain is kelcyhyde.com if that helps.

Comment: so, does the file exists? i bet it's wordpress referencing old file path migration.. it's in the db and config file, but i can't remember which one..

Comment: Which file are you referring to? It's been a long couple of days, so I'm going to be slow getting what people are referring to unless they spell it out.

I just noticed when I activated all of the plugins, the website shows a different homepage whether I'm logged in or not.

Comment: on the error.. the `wp-includes/class-wp-query.php` one. perhaps you have to take a look  on `wp-settings.php` and ensure the path reflect the new one..

Comment: The class-wp-query.php does exist in the includes folder, and line 151 on wp-settings.php references /class-wp-query.php.

Comment: I see in my posts table that things like images are referencing the subdomain where I migrated from. Is there a blanket renaming command I can use, and if so, could that possible fix this issue as well?

Comment: regarding the image, perhaps [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/125230/mysql-search-and-replace-some-text-in-a-field) can give you some insight. about the `wp-settings.php`, does the path is correct? if so, i could only think it's permission issue..

Comment: So this query fixed my problem of not being able to access the dashboard: 

UPDATE newprefix_options SET option_name = REPLACE (option_name, 'oldprefix_', 'newprefix_') WHERE option_name LIKE 'oldprefix_%';

Comment: yes, but i suggest you try on local first.. `UPDATE posts SET posts_content = REPLACE (option_name, 'old_site_url', 'new_site_url') WHERE Posts_content LIKE 'old_site_url_%'; ` -- ps. i suggest that answer for replacing the image url, not options..