# mysql truncate column data with specific text

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table customer, column reference. 1000 lines of data

There are alot of reference data. 'Customer credit note XXXXX'
I want to replace 'Customer credit note'  with ''

How do I do that?

Comment: Have you looked at the MySQL manual there are some text manipulation functions that will do this for you?

Comment: Start [by looking here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html)

Comment: Similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125230/mysql-search-and-replace-some-text-in-a-field

Answer (score 1):

To correct the data in the table, UPDATE them with a REPLACE

```
UPDATE customer 
SET reference = REPLACE(reference, 'Customer credit note ', '')
WHERE reference LIKE 'Customer credit note %';
```

Comment: Would have been better to just Dup it