# How to `Insert` a new folder into a path in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql

**Fiddle link:**

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/04d439/1

**Problem:**

I need to update a few records. Specifically the file_path column.

All I need to do is, add a folder called 'Archive' before the file.

For example, a record out of the table:

```
\\server\data\folder1\folder2\file.docx
```

How can I update path to the following:

```
\\server\data\folder1\folder2\Archive\file.docx
```

Simply adding 'Archive` folder before the file.

This is what I have tried, but too much copy and pasting values.

```
update file_path set path = '\\\\server\\data\\folder1\\folder2\\Archive\\file.docx' where id = 1;
```

How can this be achieved, without writing out the path?

Comment: If you want to do this to all records, just search and replace https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125230/mysql-search-and-replace-some-text-in-a-field.  If you only need to do some records, change your update to include where id = 1 OR id = 2 OR id =99 to list the records you want changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE file_path
SET path = CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(path, 
                                  '\\', 
                                  LENGTH(path) - LENGTH(REPLACE(path, '\\', ''))), 
                  '\\Archive\\',
                  SUBSTRING_INDEX(path, '\\', -1));
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=383a83ff7f7e1c6af07d49a9e9ab0558)

Comment: Absolutely the same expression, from CONCAT till the last parenthesis.